# Year 13 Vectors - Cross Product Help

Tags: vectors

Q: The lines $L1$ and $L2$ have equations

$$L1: \mathbf{r} = 
\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\1\end{bmatrix} + s\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\-2\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$L2: \mathbf{r}= 
\begin{bmatrix}-3\\-11\\5\end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix}-1\\3\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

Calculate the *sine* of the angle between $L1$ and $L2$:

My solution:

$$\mathbf{a}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\-2\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad \mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix}-1\\3\\1\end{bmatrix},$$

$$|\mathbf{a}|=\sqrt{2^2 + 1^2 + (-2)^2}=\sqrt{4 + 1 + 4}=\sqrt{9}=3,$$

$$|\mathbf{b}|=\sqrt{(-1)^2 + 3^2 + 1^2}=\sqrt{1 + 9 + 1}= \sqrt{11},$$

$$\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\-2\end{bmatrix}\times \begin{bmatrix}-1\\3\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}7\\0\\7\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf{n},$$

$$|\mathbf{n}|=\sqrt{(7^2 + 0^2 + 7^2}=\sqrt{49 + 0 + 49}=\sqrt{98}= 7\sqrt{2}.$$

Using 
$$\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b} =|\mathbf{a}|\,|\mathbf{b}|\sin\theta\,\hat{n}$$

then $$7\sqrt{2}=3\sqrt{11}\sin\theta$$

so $$\sin\theta=\frac{7\sqrt{2}}{3\sqrt{11}}=\frac{7\sqrt{22}}{33}.$$

Is My Solution Correct?

The Textbook Gives The Answer As $\sqrt{22}$

Comment: I took at a look at this but didn't bother to read it as it looks too messy & hard to understand for me. I suggest you use what's shown at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to edit your question to make it easier for us to read. Thanks.

Comment: A classmate of mine illustrated the answer to the original to me, but I was stuck on part b) of the same question and I've tried to do my best on it. Help appreciated.

Comment: Note that the answer for $\sin \theta$ cannot be $\sqrt{22}$, because $-1\leq \sin \theta \le 1$ for all real $\theta$.

Comment: I fixed the TeX somewhat. Observe that you are to wrap the entire formulas/equations/whatnot with dollar.signs. You **don't** want to wrap every single symbol separately. Using doubled dollar signs *displays* a formula/equation, center on a separate line, recommended at least when the formula/equation is long or containg matrices. And, for heaven's sake don't wrap pieces of text with dollars. Within dollars there are no *words*, just individual letters. So inside dollars `and` becomes $and$, the product of the variables $a$, $n$, and $d$.

Comment: If you want a word typeset in *italics* use single asterisks `*italics*` much the same way you use double asterisks to get **bold**. In math mode (=inside dollars) it is slightly preferrable to use `\mathbf{a}` to get a boldface symbol, but that's fine tuning. Anyway, your attempt is appreciated!

Comment: And, your calculation is correct. I would not have bothered with the cross product. I would have calculated $\cos\theta$ using the dot product, and then figured out the sine from
$$\sin\theta=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}.$$ Because the angle between two line is in the interval $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$ we can use the plus sign always.